# Accent insensitive query in the contacts provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I want to make a contacts query where the selection is in the form `Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?`, but I want the search to be accent insensitive.

If I use `COLLATE LOCALIZED`, it works with the `=` operator, not with the `like`.

Android's default contact app somehow manages to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making a query to `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI` and using a "selection", make a query to `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` where the query is added as an additional path segment.